# How does Silverlight Loaded event work?

Tags: silverlight

I posted this on Silverlight.net ([here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/215326.aspx)).  I guess they are as stumped about how load works as everyone else because I didn't get a response.

The MSDN documentation found says :

*You can handle LayoutUpdated instead of Loaded. LayoutUpdated is the last "object lifetime" event in the sequence of enabling a control in Silverlight UI. The main limitation of LayoutUpdated is that the initialization is possibly not the only time that LayoutUpdated is raised.*

**(Question 1)** The inverse of the above statement implies that the Loaded event can be relied on to be raised only once.  Is that correct??

Also the MSDN document referenced above says (with respect the Loaded Event):

*Occurs when a FrameworkElement has been constructed and added to the object tree.  (Inherited from FrameworkElement.)*

The above statement is repeated and emphisized in the document referenced here which appears to try to reconcile the issue.

However the detail documentation for the Loaded Event says:

*In Silverlight, the Loaded event is not guaranteed to occur after the template is applied. This might be an issue for you if you are using the Loaded event for a relatively common control scenario: you want to examine the visual tree...*

**(Question 2)** This is very confusing.  (The above two statements are contradictory) OR (it is possible for a FrameworkElement to be constructed and added to the object tree AND the temlate has not been applied).  The latter seems unlikely since the second msdn statement references the visual tree.  Please clarify which of these statements is correct.  
**(Question 3)** Also, does "not guranteed to occur after" mean that it may occur before, or it just wont occur at all?

Answer (score 3):

The Loaded event will be raised only once, unless you remove the object from the object tree and re-add it later, at which point everything will happen all over again.

I can confirm that the Loaded event can happen before the template is applied. I do all my template and visual tree examination operations, including any last-minute initialization, in OnApplyTemplate() just for this reason.

"Not guaranteed to occur after" refers to the order of operations, yes. Loaded will always happen after an object is added to the object tree.

Comment: Sander, your response very helpful, thank you very much.
The MS documentation should read "Occurs EACH TIME a framework element is added to the visual tree"
I have a menu control I'm working on that uses a popup control.  I do not explicity  remove it from the visual tree but
it's visibiliy is toggled (popup.isvisible is set to false).  In any case, the loaded event is occuring more than once.
However the second time around I get this error: "Element is already the child of another element".  This leads me to beleive
it is not removed from the visual tree so I don't understand whats going on.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps in your scenario some ancestor is being moved around in the object tree, not the control itself. This will also cause your control (and all others in the part of the tree that got re-added) to raise the Loaded event. If you have some more information about where exactly the error is being raised (what is the method being called and when), I might be able to assist further.

Comment: I also suggest you handle the Unloaded event - this may give you some clues as to when/why your object is removed from the tree (and by what). Unloaded is raised every time your object or an ancestor is removed from the object tree.

Comment: OK, the question now is when is an object removed from the visual tree?  I'm not doing any removing or moving around that I know of, unless toggling visibility counts as removing. "Unloaded is raised every time your object or an ancestor is removed from the object tree."  The object tree or the visual tree?  BTW I added a counter to my class that is incremented on load, decremented on unload.  They appear to be working as you say, I still cant find the reason for the error.

Comment: I meant the object tree, yes. As far as I know, the Loaded/Unloaded events do not have any specific relation to the visual tree, they are mainly concerned with the object tree. I may be wrong here but I'm fairly confident of this (the visual tree is mostly kept hidden from the developer in Silverlight, so in general, I recommend you ignore it even exists, unless implementing some feature hacks around built-in controls). Toggling visibility should not be unloading any controls. Try setting a breakpoint in the event handler and seeing when specifically these events happen, perhaps?